# Flutter Unit testing Firebase SignIn/Authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase, unit-testing, firebase-authentication

I am new to unit testing on flutter but I want to try write some unit test to the signup process for a small application I created.

```
import 'package:counter/models/user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<UserModel?> signUpUser(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final UserCredential userCredential =
          await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email.trim(), password: password.trim());
      final User? firebaseUser = userCredential.user;
      if (firebaseUser != null) {
        return UserModel(
            id: firebaseUser.uid,
            email: firebaseUser.email,
            displayName: firebaseUser.displayName);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      developer.log(e.message ?? "");
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> signOutUser() async {
    final User? firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    }
  }

  Future<UserModel?> signInUser(String email, String password) async{
    try{
      final UserCredential userCredential = await  _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      final User? firebaseUser = userCredential.user;
      if(firebaseUser != null){
        return UserModel(
          id:firebaseUser.uid,
          email: firebaseUser.email,
          displayName: firebaseUser.displayName
        );
      }else{
        return null;
      }
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      developer.log(e.message ?? "");
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried following a few guides and videos but most of them are older and I couldn't figure out how to apply it to my code , I would like to know If and how to unit test this and if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll need to use the flutter_test package which provides utilities for testing Flutter apps. Here's an example of how you could write unit tests for your signup process:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:counter/services/authentication_service.dart';

// Mock FirebaseAuth instance
class MockFirebaseAuth extends Mock implements FirebaseAuth {}

void main() {
  group('AuthenticationService', () {
    late AuthenticationService authService;
    late MockFirebaseAuth mockFirebaseAuth;

    setUp(() {
      mockFirebaseAuth = MockFirebaseAuth();
      authService = AuthenticationService();
      authService.firebaseAuth = mockFirebaseAuth;
    });

    test('signUpUser returns a UserModel if signup successful', () async {
      when(mockFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: anyNamed('email'), password: anyNamed('password')))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => FakeUserCredential());

      final result = await authService.signUpUser('test@example.com', 'password');

      expect(result, isA<UserModel>());
    });

    test('signUpUser returns null if signup fails', () async {
      when(mockFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: anyNamed('email'), password: anyNamed('password')))
          .thenThrow(FirebaseAuthException(code: 'error'));

      final result = await authService.signUpUser('test@example.com', 'password');

      expect(result, null);
    });
  });
}

// Fake implementation of UserCredential for mocking
class FakeUserCredential extends Fake implements UserCredential {
  @override
  User get user => FakeUser();
}

// Fake implementation of User for mocking
class FakeUser extends Fake implements User {
  @override
  String get uid => 'fakeUid';

  @override
  String get email => 'fake@example.com';

  @override
  String? get displayName => 'Fake User';
}
```